# filter_condition_callback function stopped working after using $collection

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('increment_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('customer_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('customer_email')
        ->addFieldToSelect('created_at')
        ->addFieldToSelect('grand_total')
        ->addFieldToSelect('base_grand_total')
        ->addFieldToSelect('status')
        ->addFieldToSelect('order_currency_code')
        ->addFieldToSelect('store_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('billing_name')
        ->addFieldToSelect('shipping_name')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId())
        ->setIsCustomerMode(true);        

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _avansFilter($collection, $column)
    {
     if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                return $this;
            }
            $orderId = $collection->getData();
            $CustomerEmail = $orderId[0]['customer_email'];
            $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $CustomerEmail)->addFieldToSelect('*');
            //$Subtotal = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId)->getSubtotal();

             foreach($orders as $order){
                $OID = $order->getData();
                $OrderIncrementId = $OID['increment_id'];


                    $DiscountAmount = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($OrderIncrementId)->getDiscountAmount();
                    $DiscountshippingTotal = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($OrderIncrementId)->getDiscountshippingTotal();
                    $FeeAmount = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($OrderIncrementId)->getFeeAmount();
                    $ShippingAmount = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($OrderIncrementId)->getShippingAmount();
                    $Subtotal = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($OrderIncrementId)->getSubtotal();
                    $Grandtotal = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($OrderIncrementId)->getGrandTotal();
                    $AvansMethod = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($OrderIncrementId)->getAvansMethod();

                    $GSubTotal = $Subtotal + $FeeAmount + $DiscountAmount + $DiscountshippingTotal;



                    if($AvansMethod == 2){
                        $GSubTotal = $GSubTotal / 2;
                        if($GSubTotal > $value){
                            $SearchID .= "$OrderIncrementId";
                        }
                    }           
                    if($AvansMethod == 3){
                        $GSubTotal = '00,00';
                        $SearchID .= "$OrderIncrementId";
                    }

                }
            Mage::log(''.$this.'', null, 'grids.log', true);    

            $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
                "increment_id like ?"
            , "%$value%");


            return $this;

    }
```

I do not know why but after i added `$orderId = $collection->getData();` in my `protected function _avansFilter($collection, $column)` the function seems to not return anything when i use  `return $this`.

When i remove this line `$orderId = $collection->getData();`  the variable `$this` is starting again to be working.(ofcource returing not the data i need but returning any data)

It is somehow stopping return any data when i use $orderId = $collection->getData(); in the function, why ?

Looking forward for your response

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your `_avansFilter` method does, but calling `$collection->getData()` will load the collection. I mean it will run the sql query and retrieve all the data.
calling `$collection->load()` or `getData` after this point will not run the sql query again. It will return the same results as before even if you added more filters or orders to the collection object in the meantime.
`$collection` and `$this->getCollection()` most probably are the same thing since objects are passed by reference in PHP5.
So your changes to the collection are not taken into consideration after calling `getData`.

Comment: I've made a lot of tests and simply when i remove `$orderId = $collection->getData();` the variable `$this` is starting again to return any results. I do not understand why? Can you suggest any changes to my code regarding this problem ?